# How to validate the OTP received for mobile number verification using Firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to add mobile number verification module in my application. I am using firebase for this and OTP is getting successfully sent to the particular mobile number but I want to validate whether the OTP entered is equal to the OTP sent to the respective mobile number.

I **don't want to use** the following code,

```
  mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(FirebasePhoneActivity.this, "Verification Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        Toast.makeText(FirebasePhoneActivity.this, "Verification Failed, Invalid credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
break;
```

because using the above code lets the user Sign-In using mobile number. I want only to cross verify the OTP and don't want to Sign-In using MOBILE NUMBER.

```
  @Override
    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
        codeSent = s;

        resendToken = forceResendingToken;
    }
```

Using the above code doesn't give the code that's sent but a random string value.

```
 PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

        codeReceivedByUser = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();

    }
```

The above code is getting called only when the OTP is received to his mobile and not in someone else's mobile(case when we give other person's mobile number)

Is there any way to validate the OTP when sent to someone else's mobile without using signInWithCredential method? Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you shared shows nothing about the realtime database, so I removed that tag. Please only apply tags that are relevant to the question you're asking.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sure. Thanks for the tip. Can I get any help on the issue that I am facing?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code(call method one by one)

private void setListener() {

```
        callbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Verification Completed" + phoneAuthCredential, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                try {
                    ActivityHelper.dismissProgressDialog();

                } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    CustomLogHandler.printErrorlog(throwable);
                }
                if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                    Toast.makeText(context ,"Verification Failed" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Verification Failed" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Verification Failed" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                isResendClicked = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                try {
                    ActivityHelper.dismissProgressDialog();
                } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    CustomLogHandler.printErrorlog(throwable);
                }
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Code sent to your registered device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                isResendClicked = false;
                verificationId = s;
                resendtoken = forceResendingToken;
            }
        };

    }




  private void callGetOTPApi() {
        try {
            ActivityHelper.showProgressDialog(getActivity(), "Loading...", false);
            PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(number, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, getActivity(), callbacks);

        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            CustomLogHandler.printErrorlog(throwable);
        }


    }
```